# How to insert data in different database using mysql stored procedure in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a stored procedure which insert data from one database to another. Stored procedure is working fine in mysql but when i call through hibernate, its not working.

```
        DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERTDATA`(stdID BIGINT)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
          BEGIN
            -- ERROR
          ROLLBACK;
        END;
        DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
         BEGIN
            -- WARNING
         ROLLBACK;
        END;

        START TRANSACTION;

        INSERT INTO `db2`.`std`
        SELECT * FROM stdDetails WHERE studID=stdID;

        COMMIT;

END
```

> // working fine if i do this

```
call INSERTDATA(1);
```

> But

```
 Query procQry = session.createSQLQuery( "CALL ARCHIVEEVENTDATA(?)");                           
                            procQry.setParameter(0,examEventID);
                procQry.executeUpdate();
                transaction.commit();
```

> Not working for me :(

Note : Both databases are on same server